# What should we have as output for model.evaluate

Tags: tensorflow

I started tensorflow not long ago and I am currently working on CNNs and particularly on sign-language mnist to recognize sign language. After creating and running my model I evaluate it with model.evaluate with 7172 images. The problem is that at the output of the evaluator I have 7172/1 which in my opinion should be 7172/7172. In addition, I have a much too long verbose in my opinion. I've tried changing several settings in my model but nothing works. Can someone help me understand this problem better?

1.here is a portion of my code

```
training_images = np.expand_dims(training_images, axis = 3)
testing_images = np.expand_dims(testing_images, axis = 3)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               horizontal_flip = True,
                               rotation_range = 40,
                               width_shift_range=0.2,
                               height_shift_range=0.2,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               fill_mode ='nearest',
                               zoom_range = 0.2)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', 
                                                                input_shape=(28,28,1)),
                               tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
                               tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation = 'relu'),
                               tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
                               tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                               tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu),
                               tf.keras.layers.Dense(26,activation = tf.nn.softmax)])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                                             metrics =['accuracy'])
history = model.fit_generator(train_datagen.flow(training_images, training_labels, 
                                                                   batch_size = 32),
                             steps_per_epoch=len(training_images) / 32, epochs = 15, 
                        validation_data = validation_datagen.flow(testing_images,                                                       
                                                          testing_labels,batch_size = 32),
                        validation_steps=len(testing_images) / 32)
model.evaluate(testing_images, testing_labels)
```

2.And here the exit that I get

```
7172/1[=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================] - 2s 218us/sample - loss: 277.3631 - accuracy: 0.4357
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the same code with the sign mnist dataset in Google colab and found that you need to replace this code snippet:

```
#training_images = np.expand_dims(training_images, axis = 3)
#testing_images = np.expand_dims(testing_images, axis = 3)
```

with this below given code snippet to execute the program successfully.

```
training_images = training_images.reshape(training_images.shape[0], *(28, 28, 1))
testing_images = testing_images.reshape(testing_images.shape[0], *(28, 28, 1))
```

After running the code:

```
model.evaluate(testing_images, testing_labels)   #model ran on 5 epochs
```

Output:

```
172/172 [==============================] - 4s 24ms/step - loss: 189.1395 - accuracy: 0.4999
[189.13946533203125, 0.4999089539051056]
```

`model.evaluate()` - returns the loss value and metrics values for the model.

Please refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#api_overview_a_first_end-to-end_example) for more details in `.evaluate()`.